# the best way to censor words in golang

Tags: string, text, go

What is the best pattern to censor specific abuse words in string with golang?

For example censor this text:

> Mark is a porn-star.

to

> Mark is a p*******r.

from a list of words that we pass to it.

Comment: You will need to [edit] to be more specific with what you're trying to accomplish. Before you edit though, please read about the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem), so that you can understand the pitfalls in what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved with ["strings"](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) library functions.

Look at this example:
[Golang simple world filter o censor](https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-simple-word-filter-or-censor-example)